# Moderator actions - programming question transferred from SO to Unix

Tags: discussion, migration, moderation

The question is [Getting text from last marker to EOF in POSIX.2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10374/getting-text-from-last-marker-to-eof-in-posix-2)
Albeit about programming it was transferred to Unix. No button to ask moderator. I've flagged it for moderator attention on SO with the question "why", got -10 to flag weight and no answer.

The question is why was it moved? Along with plenty of sed/awk questions of the kind doesn't it belong with the SO?

Comment: It's a borderline case. Not exactly programming, but a programming task. You'll always get cases which could be argued either way.

Comment: It's shell scripting, which is listed in the U/L FAQ as being on topic.

Answer (score 4):

Considering the quality and quantity of the answers provided at Unix.SE, I think whoever that masked mod was that migrated made the right choice.

Comment: Yes, it's hard to argue with that migration.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't have considered your question off-topic for Stack Overflow. But it's definitely on-topic on Unix.SE, too.

On Stack Overflow, you had [one answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10374/getting-text-from-last-marker-to-eof-in-posix-2/10375#10375) after 21 hours, and even [complained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5487267/getting-text-from-last-marker-to-eof-in-posix-2?noredirect=1) that your question wasn't getting attention. On Unix.SE, you received 3 answers within 6 hours, proposing many more solutions, even with [benchmarks](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10374/getting-text-from-last-marker-to-eof-in-posix-2/10389#10389). So now you're complaining about the migration… why?

[Create an account](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/login) on the Unix site. Enter the same OpenID as on Stack Overflow, that way your accounts will be associated. Then you'll be able to “claim” your question on Unix.SE, edit it, gain rep from it, mark an accepted answer and so on.

Answer (score 2):

This is a borderline case.

The goal of migration is to get questions *answered*, by sending them to the best expert community for that topic.

Anyway, if you feel the question does not get a good answer over at U&L, feel free to delete it, and re-ask on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Can't he just request that it be unmigrated? (It has a couple answers on UL now that would be lost, but that's what happens :-\\)

Comment: Actually i think there are more relevant people on SO, that's why i've asked it there. I've negative experience with asking on fellow sites. The problem was too in the fact that i've specified the tags not exactly wrong but too "unused". A **posix** keyword is not subscribed to, it seems, it didn't get that much audience as **linux** or **sed**

Comment: Thank You, Jeff! I'd rather delete my account instead.